# Generating single JSON file for two tables

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create a single JSON file displaying data from two different tables. I can manage to fetch them, however I don't understand how to concatenate the two arrays. I am new to JSON. Any suggestions/tutorials would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Here the expected JSON:

```
    {
"array1":[
{"days":"1","id":"1","image":"image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg, image4.jpg"},{"days":"2","id":"1","image":"elephanta.jpg,image2.jpg,image1.jpg,imagica.jpg"},
{"days":"3","id":"1","image":"image3"},{"days":"4","id":"2","image":"image4"}
],
"array2":[
{"id":"1","image_1":"image1.jpg"},
{"id":"2","image_1":"image2.jpg"},
{"id":"3","image_1":"image3.jpg"}
]
}
```

but the JSON that I get is this:

```
{
"array1":[
{"days":"1","id":"1","image":"image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg, image4.jpg"},{"days":"2","id":"1","image":"elephanta.jpg,image2.jpg,image1.jpg,imagica.jpg"},
{"days":"3","id":"1","image":"image3"},{"days":"4","id":"2","image":"image4"}
]},
{"array2":[
{"id":"1","image_1":"image1.jpg"},
{"id":"2","image_1":"image2.jpg"},{"id":"3","image_1":"image3.jpg"
}
]}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select * from image_data";
    $sql1 = "select * from one";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $imageArray = array();
    $imageArray1 = array();
    $imageArray["array1"] = array();
    $imageArray1["array2"] = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["days"] = $row["id"];
        $tmp["id"] =   $row["place_id"];
        $tmp["image"] = $row["image"];
        array_push($imageArray["array1"], $tmp);
       // $imageArray[] = $row;
    }

        while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $row["id"];
        $tmp["image_1"] = $row["image"];

        array_push($imageArray1["array2"], $tmp);
       // $imageArray[] = $row;
    }
            echo json_encode($imageArray);
  echo ",";
  echo json_encode($imageArray1);
    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Instead of using `array_push($imageArray["array1"], $tmp);`, why not try: `$tmp[] = $imageArray["array1"]);`?

Comment: Instead of separately serializing each array and trying to *manually* build the JSON, create an object which *contains* the two arrays and serialize that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 2 sub arrays to belong to the same array then use only one array and address the 2 sub arrays like this when loading them

```
$imageArray["array1"][] = $tmp;
```

and

```
$imageArray["array2"][] = $tmp;
```

Amended code

```
<?php
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select * from image_data";
    $sql1 = "select * from one";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $imageArray = array();       // <- removed other arrays

    while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["days"] = $row["id"];
        $tmp["id"] =   $row["place_id"];
        $tmp["image"] = $row["image"];
        $imageArray["array1"][] = $tmp;    // <- address array like this
    }

    while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $row["id"];
        $tmp["image_1"] = $row["image"];

        $imageArray["array2"][] = $tmp;    // <- address array like this
    }
    echo json_encode($imageArray);         // <- only one json_encode

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

I would have done it this way using `stdObject` and selecting the specific data from the tables, and using `mysqli_fetch_obect()` so there is a lot less you have to do `woman-draulically`

```
<?php
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    // only select what you want
    $sql = "select id,place_id,image from image_data";
    $sql1 = "select id,image from one";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $imageObject = new stdObject();

    while($row =mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
        $imageObject->array1[] = $row;
    }

    while($row =mysqli_fetch_object($result1))
    {
        $imageObject->array2[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($imageObject);
?>
```

Comment: i used urs :D...was attempting the earlier suggestions..but then saw ur post..it did d wrk :)...thanks

Comment: @PoojaGangurde He was interested in knowing if it is was the first version or the second one?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just made an attempt and every time I do, you answer first... Grrrrr... :P

Comment: Sorry @PraveenKumar Just trying to catch up with your very impressive Rep hehehe

Comment: @PraveenKumar Did we agree on the solution?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Definitely... :)